# socket.io nodejs : use database to store all sockets clients?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

At the moment, i store **sockets** for each **client** to emit.

```
clients[myID] = socket;
```

but i wonder if there is a lot of user it will be a problem.
Is that it can be much to store **clients** in database like express store sessionID (using redis) ?

(i must to stock the entire **socket** to make it work ? so, it's big !)

*What's the best way ?*

I saw there was some time that could be do something like that:

```
sio.set('store',...
```

*what is it ? How to use it ?*

*Or, i can store using redis normally ?*

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store just socket id and then access it later using `io.sockets.sockets[id]`.

If you are trying to store socket in one process and then deal with it in another, that would obviously fail anyway.